# Replace HEX characters (\x20) from string with ASCII space

Tags: linux, bash, replace, hex, ascii

I'm running a shell command which returns raw string that is a combination of ASCII and Hex chars. The character it embeds is space-chars in hex. Below is the output:

```
KINGSTON\x20SV100S2
ST380011A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
Maxtor\x206L300S0\x20\x20
```

How can I replace all the `\x20` into single ASCII space character?

Expected output:

```
KINGSTON SV100S2
ST380011A
Maxtor 6L300S0
```

P.S the string is stored in a bash variable, hence I would prefer a solution that doesn't input file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only replace `\x20` and nothing else use `sed`:

```
sed 's/\\x20/ /g' <<< "$output"
```

or

```
yourCommand | sed 's/\\x20/ /g'
```

To replace all escape sequences use `echo -n` (as kvantour already pointed out) or even better, the more portable `printf %b` which can also assign directly to variables without using `$()`:

```
printf -v output %b "$output"
```

Comment: +1 for `printf -v` which is very efficient and can also change other backslash  sequences if required, otherwise could also be done in expansion `"${output//'\x20'/ }"`

Answer (score 2):

You can try Perl also

```
$ perl -e ' BEGIN { print "KINGSTON\x20SV100S2","\n" } '
KINGSTON SV100S2
$
```

or

you can export it to environment

```
$ export a="KINGSTON\x20SV100S2"
$ perl -e ' BEGIN { $x=$ENV{a}; $x=~s/\\x(\d{2})/chr(hex($1))/ge; print $x,"\n" } '
KINGSTON SV100S2
$
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to use `echo -e`

```
$ echo -e "KINGSTON\x20SV100S2"
KINGSTON SV100S2
```

> **`-e`**     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

Or just use `printf`

```
$ printf "KINGSTON\x20SV100S2"
KINGSTON SV100S2
```

Comment: thanks, re-assigning the variable with echo helped to solve this. `HD_NAME=$(echo -e "$HD_NAME")`

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is more portable than `echo -e`. You need to use `%b` format.
 As per `help printf`:

> `%b`  expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument

Define a utility function:

```
expbs() { printf '%b\n' "$@"; }
```

Then use it as:

```
expbs 'KINGSTON\x20SV100S2'
KINGSTON SV100S2

expbs 'ST380011A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20'
ST380011A

expbs 'Maxtor\x206L300S0\x20\x20'
Maxtor 6L300S0
```